# Comparison of dictionary keys with tolerances

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'100.1125': '353.2216'; '151.0977': '131.2193'; '102.0553': '103.6859'; '103.0209': '104.624'}

d2 = {'100.1124': '352.2220'; '200': '131.2193'; '300': '103.6859'; '400': '104.624'; '103.0545': '448.3161'}
```

I wish to loop through keys in `d1` and check for their presence in `d2`, +/- a specified tolerance. If true, I wish to then compare the associated values for each dictionary key and check whether they also match with a given tolerance. Where a match is found, I would like to write the output to one file (`Output_match.txt`). When no match is found, I would like to write the `d1` key and associated value to a second file (`Output_nomatch.txt`).

So, let's say tolerance for dictionary key comparison is +/- `0.0002`. Tolerance for value comparison is +/- `5`.

I would expect `Output_match.txt` to contain:

```
key ---- value
100.1125 ---- 353.2216
```

I would expect `Output_nomatch.txt` to contain:

```
key ---- value
151.0977 ---- 131.2193
102.0553 ---- 103.6859
103.0209 ---- 104.624
```

Could anybody offer any assistance here?

EDIT:

Apologies for having not provided my current attempt:

```
with open(os.path.join(path,'out_true.txt'), 'w') as opt_true, open(os.path.join(path,'out_false.txt'), 'w') as opt_false:
header = ('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n') % ('file1_mz', 'file1_rt', 'file2_mz', 'file2_rt')
opt_true.write(header)
for key in d1.keys():
    upper_mz = float(key) + (float(key) * (ppm*0.000001))
    lower_mz = float(key) - (float(key) * (ppm*0.000001))
    upper_rt = float(dict1[key]) + (2*rt_shift)
    lower_rt = float(dict1[key]) - (2*rt_shift)
    for key2 in d2:
        upper_mz2 = float(key2) + (float(key2) * (ppm*0.000001))
        lower_mz2 = float(key2) - (float(key2) * (ppm*0.000001))
        upper_rt2 = float(dict2[key2]) + (2*rt_shift)
        lower_rt2 = float(dict2[key2]) - (2*rt_shift)
        if float(upper_mz) >= float(lower_mz2) and float(lower_mz) <= float(upper_mz2) and float(upper_rt) >= float(lower_rt2) and float(lower_rt) <= float(upper_rt2):
            opt_true.write(('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n') % (str(key), str(dict1[key]), str(key2), str(dict2[key2])))
            #print float(key)
            a[key] = d1[key]
            b[key2] = d2[key2]
for key in d1.keys():
    if not key in a:
        opt_false.write(('%s\t%s\n') % (str(key), d1[key]))
for key2 in d2.keys():
    if not key2 in b:
        opt_false.write(('%s\t%s\n') % (str(key), d1[key]))

opt_true.close()
opt_false.close()
```

Comment: This isn't a tutorial service; where is your implementation, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: What if there are multiple matches for the same key? Should the key & value from `d1` be  written to `Output_match.txt` more than once? e.g. for tolerance 0.1, key `d1 = 100.0` and keys `100.01` and `99.99` in `d2`, the key from `d1` would be output twice.

Comment: @mhawke you're absolutely right, and I should have specified this possibility in my original post. It is possible that some keys in d1 overlap several keys in d2.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, using the built-in function [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs), in order to calculate the distance in a simple way:

```
d1 = {'100.1125': '353.2216', '151.0977': '131.2193',
      '102.0553': '103.6859', '103.0209': '104.624'}
d2 = {'100.1124': '352.2220', '200': '131.2193',
      '300': '103.6859', '400': '104.624', '103.0545': '448.3161'}

key_tolerance, value_tolerance = 0.0002, 5
output_match, output_nomatch = [], []

for i, j in d1.items():
    for k, l in d2.items():
        if (abs(float(i)-float(k)) <= key_tolerance and
            abs(float(j)-float(l)) <= value_tolerance):
            output_match.append((i, j))
        else:
            output_nomatch.append((i, j))

print(output_match, '----', set(output_nomatch) - set(output_match), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[('100.1125', '353.2216')]
----
{('102.0553', '103.6859'), 
 ('103.0209', '104.624'), 
 ('151.0977', '131.2193')}
```